# How can I make Docker Images / Volumes (Flask, Python) accessible for my host machine (macOS)?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running the latest macOS (Sierra) with Docker and Kitematic installed. I am also using Virtualbox for emulation.

I want to use the uwsgi-nginx-flask image but I have no idea how I can make the python files and the nginx directory inside my container accessible from outside the virtual machine ?

Haven't found anything about that on the website either.

Answer (score 1):

Folders between the host and containers can be mapped and mounted by using the -v tag during runtime.

```
$ docker run -it -v /host/directory:/container/directory imagename:tag
```

You can alternatively use docker cp to copy stuff inside and outside of the container. For example

```
$ docker cp /path/to/file ContainerName:/path/inside/container
```

or

```
$ docker cp ContainerName:/path/inside/container/file .
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !  I am getting there... But what I don't understand is where I can find the virtual folder path ?

Comment: Let's say I want to map it like this : docker run -it -v ~/Users/Dan/MyDockerFolder/docker-flask:/container/directory imagename:tag

Comment: Where can I find the virtual directory path (here --> :/container/directory) ?

Comment: For that you need to enter into the container using docker exec -it containerID bash.

Comment: Once you are inside the container, you can see the complete directory structure just like any other linux box.

Answer (score 0):

you can mount the host directory to docker container which will be shared between host and docker

`docker run --name container_image -d -v ~/host_dir:/container_dir docker_image`

Comment: Hi, does this also work the same when I am using Kitematic ? Please have a look at the GUI of Kitematic, here is what I see --> http://imgur.com/8fEsi1m

Comment: It seems like I can configure it inside Kitematic or am I wrong ?

Comment: yes you can do it, I haven't used kinematics but based on the documentation [here](https://kitematic.com/docs/managing-volumes/)

Comment: yes you configured it inside you can notice that there is no local folder which means its not shared volume.